# Continous deployement to server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, heroku, deployment, digital-ocean

I'm building a personal blog website with express.I hosted it on ec2 and also hosted another version at digital ocean .But when it comes to updating my code (like i am changing a few lines or adding or removing a new feature) i have to remove all the files and re-upload and again run it.When i was using [www.heroku.com](http://heroku.com) it was easy like git push [heroku](http://heroku.com) master.How can i do similar with ec2 or digital ocean server?.(I'm using `pem` file to login to server)

Comment: Are you looking for a CI/CD solution?

Comment: Yes,is there any simplified instructions to follow

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at Code Pipeline tutorials. You can use this AWS Service to build a CI/CD use case. See:

[CodePipeline tutorials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials.html)

Answer (score 0):

As SMAC mentioned in the comments, you're looking for a CI/CD solution essentially. Heroku does a nice job of automating that for you, as do several other products out in the market. Depending on what Git provider you're using, GitHub and GitLab both provide a native solution (GitHub actions vs GitLab CI).

I'd recommend you combine that with something like AWS's ElasticBeanstalk to get a simple change/push workflow like you're looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to share documentation or tutorials for me to follow